# 2d android mmorpg game

Tags: android, opengl-es, client, mmo

I want to make an mmorpg game and i wanted to know some things before i start,
well, first of all, I know how to make games for android and i have been using canvas, opengl es 1.0/1.1 and some andengine(also opengl es 1.0/1.1). I wanted to know what i should use for a good reliable and fast mmorpg, is there any other option for a better performance?

the game is targeted only for android at the moment, i am using the android sdk and eclipse to program my game.

also, where can I learn how to make a proper client and server? because i have never had any experience with that. Untill now i had only made 2d and some 3d games, none of them were online or any kind of mmo.

if it is needed, i also have some sql and php experience from website developing. i had worked with PhpMyAdmin for my website.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should use the NDK. Write your program in **C** as opposed to C++ for easier project management. You should consider using **libevent** for asynchronous request processing. Don't use PHP for **web** interfaces, **Python** is much better at this point. C  is *the* best solution if you're willing to get **dirty**.

For developing sockets, I'd say you should use **POSIX** sockets - the industry standard. Later you should check out more advanced solutions like **ZeroMQ**. Use **PostgreSQL**/**MongoDB** depending on your requirements. Those are really advanced database management systems where you'll definitely find less overhaul then in, say, MySQL. I'd say ***MongoDB*** will fit the cause better - it's faster but doesn't feature full support for ACID data.

You should learn what you need for sockets programming in the **MAN pages** in any online/offline documentation base. It's not that hard. Here's a **server example in C**, **study it**, try to **write your own client implementation**, understand the basic principle of TCP/IP packet abstraction (by the way, this is a TCP socket, you should **check out UDP examples**, those are way more relevant for your project):

```
/*
"Arch_server" - a basic server program in C
Copyright © Juozas Domarkas 2012, all rights served
*/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void respond(int socket);

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main
(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int socket_server_fd, socket_client_fd, pid;
    socklen_t client_address_length;
    struct sockaddr_in server_address, client_address;

    if (argc != 3)
        error("Correct usage: server [host] [port]\n");

    socket_server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&server_address, sizeof(server_address));
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));

    bind(socket_server_fd, (const struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    listen(socket_server_fd, 16);
    client_address_length = sizeof(client_address);

    while (1) {
        socket_client_fd = accept(socket_server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_address, &client_address_length);
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {
            close(socket_server_fd);
            respond(socket_client_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void respond
(int socket)
{
    int n;
    char buffer[1024];

    bzero(buffer, 1024);
    n = recv(socket, buffer, 1023, 0);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("Here is the message: %s\n", buffer);
    n = send(socket,"Message received.", 17, 0);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
}
```

Depending on your experience, you should either write your server suite or **use existing solutions**. I recommend giving yourself a decent deadline (say, ***8 months***) and writing ALL the "HIGHER LEVEL" tools yourself. That way you'll get the most out of your project. Try to write them as *basic* as possible. Use low level existing solutions for better performance, study them, learn something from the 31337 h2x0r5.

Definitely check out OGRE 3D instead of GL/ES. It's an abstraction library for OpenGL. Much easier than OpenGL, better support for modern 3D development, libraries, plugins, all sorts of already developed particle, locomotion, sky/water systems.

Do not go for something like Unity3D. You have better things to do.

---

The best book to learn real C programming is "**The C programming language**" by **Dennis M. Ritchie** and **Brian W. Kernighan**.

Google has a lot of tutorials for Android development regarding the NDK. **Definitely use the NDK**. Java has good support for 3D graphics but it really isn't the right tool for the job. It's a 'niche' solution, not an industry accepted standard in game development. Regarding that, the industry uses C++ for game development. I'd seriously recommend using ONE language for the whole product life cycle. You'll need a networking server, database interface, hooks... Use C. With C++ you'll get way too much overhaul. You'll end up learning BOOST, STL, all that other crap that comes with C++. Better use C, libevent, OGRE 3D, some existing OGRE systems. All those projects have good solid documentation and are ready for prime-time use.

**Ogre3D** is intended for 3D games. You can make a "2D platform" game with it. One extra dimension isn't really that much to learn.

Learn each platform one-by-one. Don't read "all-in-one" books.

Check out the documentation of those projects.

---

Seeing as you have a lot of free time on your hands, better make yourself firstly a good plan. Organize yourself, your thoughts in one manner and try to reach for the "goal". It's really realistic to finish your MMO in, say, 4 to 5 years. That's how long it mostly takes for professionals and sometimes even indies.

Be persistent, learn something new each day, try to write code each day. Work towards ONE goal - your game. If some other project comes up - postpone it. Be a pragmatic programmer. Don't be afraid to get dirty. Take a couple of days per month off for your title, don't go to school (don't drop it!!!). Be persistent.

---

I hate doing this, but choosing a compiler, tool, platform, language is *pure* politics. I prefer "the best tool for the job", similarly to Linus Torvalds. I mostly use open source software since it does the job better. When it comes to "GPL" vs "BSD" or restrictive versus permissive software licenses, I definitely choose BSD, simply because I believe in free software versus somewhat "socially free".

A good compiler, in my opinion, would be **CLANG** from Apple's LLVM compiler collection.

Comment: until now i had used only eclipse with java, i had some experience with c but not something big, is there any way i can use eclipse instead or should i start learning more about c? also, should the game be written in c as well as the sockets? is there any book that can give me the basic idea of c and android development? btw, i want my game to be 2d, not 3d, would OGRE 3D still work for my needs? or is there something else? i had been using gl/es without specifying the z coordinate leaving it at 0 and making it look 2d. is it the same with OGRE 3D?

thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you for everything! you are AWESOME!!

Just one small question, do you have any c compiler that you recommend? anything easy to use since i haven't really used c that much.. (i remember using it for a small yes no input.. thats it..)
now all i have to do is buy the book and start learning everthing!

Comment: I also always wanted to make my own engine, like OGRE 3D, or if you may know, ANDENGINE, I want to make everything, and i mean EVERYTHING that i can from a scratch, means that if there is for example 1, 2, 3, which in this case 1 is the base of the base, and 3 is the easiest one to implement, i would like to learn 1 and make my own engine of it and libraries.  because that in the future im considering on making my own company, which means that i down want to deal with copy rights if needed.

Comment: btw, may i also email you if i face any difficulties? it would help greatly because it looks like you know a lot. right now i might not have finished high school yet, but i do have a lot of experience. btw, i just got the book you recommended. again thanks for everything! now i just have to get a my team back up for another project, because unfortunately, i am not talented in drawing at all and same goes for sounds for the game! now off to work! Again Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

To made a mmorpg server, for projects that do not refer to action games, you can use the Kraken Framework. Install with `gem install krakenlab`, and start this with `kraken -n app_name`.